# limit of inf of a sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

I wonder whether the followings are equivalent.

---

$P(\liminf_{n\to \infty} X_n \leqslant  \epsilon) = 1$, for all $\epsilon >0$,

---

and
$\liminf_{n\to \infty} X_n = 0$

Comment: Certainly not as it stands, since $X_n$ could take negative values e.g. $X_n = -1$(constant) for all $n$.

Comment: What if $X_n$ are positive?

Comment: Even if X_n are non-negative, a subset of sample space has probability zero, does not mean it is an empty set. In case this null probability set is non-empty, for those points the second statement will not hold.

Comment: If $=$ in the second condition is *almost-sure* equality, then I think the conditions are equivalent. Else null sets will create a problem.

Comment: Oh, I kinda understand. I think Teresa is correct, if a.s condition is added, it would be equivalent. Thank you all!

Comment: I don't think this is supposed to be the lim of inf of a sequence. I think it's supposed to be the liminf of the sequence.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It should be limninf of the sequence.

Comment: FYI, you can just put an entire formula between one set of dollar signs in mathjax. It is a lot easier and generally produces a **much** nicer result than switching back and forth between mathjax and plain text.